# Does this DC pump and similar ones output at different rates or at one constant pressure/air flow rate?

Tags: dc, fluid-pump

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLLq4CB9EkU
[3 minute video demonstrating a small diaphragm pump driven by a brush DC motor.]

I would like to use a DC diaphragm pump similar to this, small in size and powered by batteries. However, I would like for them to siphon liquid at different rates.
Does anybody know if these pumps only output at one constant pressure/air flow, no matter your input voltage? Or will your input voltage correspond with the output pressure/air flow of the pump?

Answer (score 1):

The diaphragm pump displaces a fixed amount of volume per cycle. Increasing the voltage increases the number of cycles per second, so normally the flow will increase when you increase the voltage. However, the flow and the pressure depend on each other. If the flow increases, the outlet pressure also increases (more gas/liquid is being forced into the rest of the system). If the outlet pressure increases past a certain point, the pump also won't have enough force to push the flow.

So using the pump by itself, you can't normally keep the flow constant and just change the pressure. Nor can you keep the pressure constant and just change the flow. You need to add a flow regulator if you really want to keep the flow constant, or a pressure regulator if you want to keep the pressure constant. On the other hand, if you can tolerate variations in the flow, you can fool around with the voltage and try to get the pressure you want. Same for trying to get the flow you want, if you can tolerate variations of pressure.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the video, it is tried with 3V and 5V. With 5V the flow is increased.

Normally the rotary motion is converted into some sort of pumping action, and the frequency of that is directly proportional to the RPM of the motor. So a higher frequency results in a higher flow. As normal DC motors have a direct dependency between voltage and RPM, the flow can be controlled by varying the voltage.

As for pressure, if I remember correctly the power is the product of airflow and air pressure or something along those lines, so if you'd increase the RPM, but keep the airflow constant, the pressure would rise and the other way round.

Comment: Thanks for that.

I'm a little confused though. If I'm trying to increase the air pressure, I have to keep the airflow constant and increase RPM. The only way to increase RPM is to increase the voltage, but the flow won't remain constant.